# How to redirect the page once the site is down in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Once my joomla site is down how can i redirect to another site.

eg.

```
**http://localhost:8081/site**   (it is orginal site)
```

if it shows ***"The page cant be displayed"*** it should automatically redirect to another site

```
**http://localhost:8081/site1** (secondary site)
```

i tryed

```
<?php

 header("http://localhost:8081/site/"); /*LIVE VERSION*/

function Redirect($http://localhost:8081/site/, $permanent = false)
{
    if (headers_sent() === false)
    {
        header('Location: ' . $http://localhost:8081/site/, true, ($permanent === true) ? 301 : 302);
    }

    exit();
}

Redirect('http:http://localhost:8081/site1/', false);
die();
?>
```

but it is not work for me.

Comment: `function Redirect($http, $permanent = false)` and  `header('Location: ' . $http,..`  and `Redirect('http://localhost:8081/site1/', false);`  try like that.

Comment: it works but, it works  in both condition, if the original site is up it is redirecting to the secondary, an if the original site is down also it move to secondary. i need once the original site is down to work. , which means once the original site shows the page cannot displayed or any other error it should move to secondary, other wise keep in original site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like that:

```
$response = http_response_code();
movepage($response);
function movePage($num){
   static $http = array (
       100 => "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue",
       101 => "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols",
       200 => "HTTP/1.1 200 OK",
       201 => "HTTP/1.1 201 Created",
       202 => "HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted",
       203 => "HTTP/1.1 203 Non-Authoritative Information",
       204 => "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content",
       205 => "HTTP/1.1 205 Reset Content",
       206 => "HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content",
       300 => "HTTP/1.1 300 Multiple Choices",
       301 => "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently",
       302 => "HTTP/1.1 302 Found",
       303 => "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other",
       304 => "HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified",
       305 => "HTTP/1.1 305 Use Proxy",
       307 => "HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect",
       400 => "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request",
       401 => "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized",
       402 => "HTTP/1.1 402 Payment Required",
       403 => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden",
       404 => "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found",
       405 => "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed",
       406 => "HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable",
       407 => "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required",
       408 => "HTTP/1.1 408 Request Time-out",
       409 => "HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict",
       410 => "HTTP/1.1 410 Gone",
       411 => "HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required",
       412 => "HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed",
       413 => "HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large",
       414 => "HTTP/1.1 414 Request-URI Too Large",
       415 => "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type",
       416 => "HTTP/1.1 416 Requested range not satisfiable",
       417 => "HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed",
       500 => "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error",
       501 => "HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented",
       502 => "HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway",
       503 => "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable",
       504 => "HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out"
   );

}
}
```

At the final function use an IF to redirect base to as you want.